# How to add subfigures in a loop

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a loop in which I would like to create three subfigures. Here is some code with the function definitions removed.

```
n = 14
dets = []
entropies = []

N = 1000


fig = plt.figure()

# The loop.
for h in xrange(2,8,2):
    for i in xrange(N):
        A = (np.random.randint(2, size=(h,n)))*2-1
        detA_Atranspose = np.linalg.det(np.dot(A, A.transpose()))
        logdetA_Atranspose = math.log(detA_Atranspose + 1,2)
        H = compute_entropy(A)
        entropies.append(H)
        dets.append(logdetA_Atranspose)

    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
    ax1.plot(dets, entropies, 'ro')

plt.show()
```

However, there is something I don't know how to do.

- In the code above, I need `ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312)
  ax2.plot(dets, entropies, 'ro')` in the second iteration and `ax3 = fig.add_subplot(313) 
  ax3.plot(dets, entropies, 'ro')` in the third to create the three subfigures. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`plt.subplots`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html) and do something like:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 3, ncols = 1)

hs = [2,8,2]

for p in xrange(3):
    h = hs[p]
    for i in xrange(N):

        # skip other code

    ax[p].plot(dets, entropies, 'ro')
```